# instaling texreg package in R

Tags: r, package, texreg

I tried to install the `texreg` package in R and am getting the following error:

```
> install.packages("texreg", "~/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.13/")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Loading Tcl/Tk interface ... done
trying URL 'http://cran.wustl.edu/src/contrib/texreg_1.06.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 204278 bytes (199 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 199 Kb
installing *source* package ‘texreg’ ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in is(signature, "list") : could not find function "className"
Error : unable to load R code in package 'texreg'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘texreg’
```

Is this a problem with my R installation? I am running 2.13 and am unfortunately unable to upgrade because I'm on a cluster.

Comment: Is this during the installation? When you're trying to use a certain function?  Please provide more information because your question currently is quite lacking in the details department.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`className` was introduced in R-2.14.0.  I suggest trying one of the [previous versions of texreg](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/texreg/).

```
> db <- news()
> news(grepl("className",Text), db=db)
Changes in version 2.14.0:

BUG FIXES

    o   In principle, S4 classes from different packages could have the same
         name.  This has not previously worked.  Changes have now been
         installed that should allow such classes and permit methods to use
         them.  New functions className() and multipleClasses() are related
         tools for programming.
```